# Query for start and end date

Tags: sql, date

I already raided the net , yet still no answers.

Well, I'm creating a hotel room reservation system.

My room availability query works fine with this query :

```
SELECT r.roominv_id, r.room_id, m.room_type,r.room_number,r.room_status
            FROM roominventory r
            INNER JOIN room AS m ON m.room_id = r.room_id
            WHERE m.room_type LIKE '%$roomtype%'
            AND r.room_status = 'available'
            AND r.roominv_id NOT IN (SELECT b.roominv_id
                       FROM reserve b
                       WHERE NOT (b.chckout < '$chckin'
                                  OR b.chckin > '$chckout'))
```

I wanted February 2 as my start date in afternoon (hotel reservations must always start after 12 noon) and February 3 as my end date ( before 12 noon )

but in my current query , if I choose February 2 as startdate and February 3 as enddate , in database, it will appear as a 2 day reservation.

So my question is:
how will I query that clients can still choose the end date from a already reserved room?

I actually saw a site that have a datepicker that have somewhat like AM/PM http://reservations.directwithhotels.com/reservation/selectDates/148/campaign/ew

BUT I'm so noob at javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your data type for `chckout` and `chckin`, you may just want to use the `BETWEEN` operator, or use inclusive equality operators (`>=`, `<=`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the `where` clause to:

```
WHERE NOT (b.chckout < '$chckin'
                              OR b.chckin >= '$chckout')
```

This assumes that chckin and chckout are stored as dates.  Otherwise you need to convert them to dates, which depends on the database . . . here are some ways:

```
date(b.chckin)
cast(b.chckin as date)
trunc(b.chckin)
```